# ¿Porque al convertir un archivo .py a .exe, me da error "Failed to excuse script tareas"?

Tags: python

Tengo este programa de ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()
v.geometry("500x500+500+200")
v.title("Prueba")


imagen = PhotoImage(file='logo.png' )
imaglebel = Label(v,image=imagen)
imaglebel.place(x= 10, y=10,)
    

v.mainloop()
```

como ven tiene un archivo externo .png y cuando quiero convertir el archivo .py a .exe si lo convierte
pero al ejecutarlo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: Error al ejecutar .exe]

estos son todos los archivos que tengo dentro de la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que se junte todo, se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: Debes indicar con qué lo estás convertiendo a .exe, en caso de que sea con `pyinstaller` debes pasarle los argumentos `--onefile` para que ese archivo sea libre e incluya la foto dentro. Pruebalo y me dices. Ejecuta la siguiente oración: `pyinstaller main.py --onfile` donde main.py es el nombre de tu archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que:

1. **En alguna parte del código exista algún error**:

   - intenta ejecutarlo con línea de comandos para verificar que no te
     salta ningún error.
   - interactúa con los elementos que tengas.
2. **Puede que la ruta de la imagen que envías en el código no sea la correcta**:

   - Verifica la ruta de la imagen. Quizá tengas que moverla al directorio `dist` donde tengas la aplicación.

Comment: Hola, lo de meter la imagen en la carpeta dist funciono , pero como hago si quiero que todo se comprima en el exe sin necesidad de meter la imagen?

Comment: Hola. Intenta utilizar el parámetro --onedir o `-F`. De esta forma debería crearte el empaquetado junto.

Comment: No hay forma. El archivo tiene que existir para que el programa lo pueda abrir, leer e incluirlo en la ejecución. No tiene mucho sentido meter todo en el EXE, sino, ¿cómo se podría abrir un archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución y para el que tenga el mismo problema lo que tiene que hacer es:

Agregar esta función a su codigo:

```
def resolver_ruta(ruta_relativa):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, ruta_relativa)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath('.'), ruta_relativa)
```

y a todos los archivos les pasamos la función en mi ejemplo es una imagen, puede ser cualquier archivo que tengas en tu codigo, ejecutalo para asegurar de que no hay ningun
error:

[image]

luego lo convertimos en .exe con pyinstaller:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez terminado el proceso de conversión del .py a .exe ahora vamos a empaquetar la imagen por si no lo hacemos al ejecutar el .exe nos saldra el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para eso en la carpeta raiz se creara un archivo .spec en mi caso se llama tareas.spec:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le damos click derecho editar con block de notas o cualquier editor de codigo y agregamos la siguiente linea con la ruta de la imagen:

```
a.datas +=[("./logo.png","logo.png","DATA")]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

PD: En el caso de querer agregar mas imagenes o archivos hacerlo de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uno debajo del otro asegurándose de que las llaves estén cerradas entre cada archivo.

Bien despues de agregar esa linea de codigo vamos al cmd y escribimos esto con el nombre
de su archivo .spec:

```
pyinstaller --onefile tareas.spec
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si todo lo hicimos bien al terminar nos dira lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si les sale error verifiquen todo.

Ahora ejecutamos el .exe que esta en la carpeta dist y efectivamente es funcional:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no les funciona lean esto:

parte 1: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/03/23/empaquetando-python-generar-archivo-exe/

parte 2: https://parzibyte.me/blog/2018/12/27/pyinstaller-assets-imagenes-archivos-ejecutable-python/